# send key presses before previous command finishes

Tags: key-bindings

When running `:browse oldfiles`, if the output goes longer than one screen then you have to hit `<space>` for the next screen or `<esc>` to go to the menu where you can type the number of the old file you want to edit.

I'm trying to create a mapping that automatically enters `<esc>` for me while the `:browse` command is still in progress, saving me a keypress. This will leave me in the command mode where I just enter a number. I tried this mapping: `nmap <F5> :bro ol \| call feedkeys('<Esc>')` but that doesn't work. The `feedkeys` function call doesn't want to kick in until the `browse` command finishes. How can I do this?

I could also use FZF, Telescope or another plugin to bring up recently-opened files, but the `:browse oldfiles` command is faster even if it's more limited than what a plugin can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution. In nvim there is the nvim_input() function call. I made a command: `command! Bro :call nvim_input('<Esc>') | bro ol`. I mapped that command to a key. When I press it, it shows me one screen full of the names of the most recently opened files, and all I have to do is type a number and enter.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need in pressing escape. Type simply `:e#<X` to open old file no. X while browsing through the list.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to seed `:e#<` ahead of time, so that all I have to do is press a number.